# Adding a textview in a constraint layout inside a recycler view shorten the constraint layout width

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, androidx, constraintlayout-guideline

I have a recycler view (dependency is com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0) inside a constraint layout (dependency is androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4) and the item for this recycler view is another constraint layout.

The issue is : **when I don't put anything inside the item layout everything is fine and my constraint layout match the width of the recycler view, but when I try to add a text view, the constraint layout width shorten to match the text view width**.

I already tried different layout_width combinations for the constraint layout and the text view (match, wrap, 0dp) but nothing work.

Here is the fragment layout containing the recycler view :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://[enter image description here][1]schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/champions_rv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_composition"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the item layout :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="Text view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[This is the result when the contraint layout is empty - it's good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVSIE.png)

[And this is the result when I try to add the textview - This is not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxoL5.png)

Comment: If you are inflating the RecyclerView item in you RecyclerView adapter (onCreateViewHolder()) are you specifying a parent or are you specifying null? If null, you need to specify a parent for the inflation to know how big it can be.

Comment: My onCreateViewHolder method was returning the view using a simple custom view class extending ConstraintLayout. I removed the custom view and remplaced it with a classic LayoutInflater.inflate line and everthing is fine now. **Thanks mate** !

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView`'s width should match its constraint, not wrap its content.  This will make the `TextView` expand to fill the `ConstraintLayout` instead:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly this is not working. In fact, that was part of my first code and the rendering is very odd (with layout_width="0dp" : https://ibb.co/3T5VyhX)

Comment: You're right, that's even weirder...hmm. I'm stumped for now, but maybe something will occur to me later.